# Transpose of rows of a column to many column

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

I want to change the data format from:

```
Gen traits  data
G1  ph  10
G2  ph  14
G1  qp  41
G2  qp  14
G1  ser 74
G2  ser 47
G1  wer 34
G2  wer 25
```

to:

```
Gen ph  qp  ser wer
G1  10  41  74  34
G2  14  14  47  25
```

How to do this in R?

Comment: Check out `pivot_wider`

Comment: In base R you could use reshape: `reshape(df,  direction = "wide", idvar = "Gen", timevar= 'traits')`

Answer (score 0):

With the `tidyr` package you can do:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Gen,
              names_from = traits,
              values_from = data)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   Gen      ph    qp   ser   wer
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 G1       10    41    74    34
#> 2 G2       14    14    47    25
```